# How to sample uniformly over a polytope knowing its vertex presentation?

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-polytopes, random-walks, sampling

Say that a convex polytope $P$ is presented as $P = \mathrm{Conv}(v_1, \dots , v_m)$.
I would like to sample over $P$, without generating the facet presentation of the polytope.
How can I do that?
I was thinking of sampling uniformly $m$ numbers $\alpha_i$ from $[0,1]$, and then writing $p = (\sum \alpha_i v_i)/(\sum \alpha_i)$, however I don't think this samples uniformly over $P$: points closer to the barycenter will be more likely...

Comment: How large are $m$ and the dimension of $P$?

Comment: m and the dimension both scales polynomially with respect to some parameter n. I need to solve the problem for the family of polytopes P_n as n increases

Comment: Since even computing the volume of polytopes is #P complete (for a reasonable interpretation of the computational problem here), I don’t think there can be an efficient general solution to uniform sampling.